# What is the best way to select array elements using an array of true/false values?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [true, true, false, false]
```

What is the best way to select the elements of `a` whose corresponding element in `b` is `true`? In this example, I expect:

```
result = [1, 2]
```

I am doing it like this:

```
zipped = a.zip(b)
zipped.select{ |z| z[1] }.map{ |n| n.first }
# => [1, 2]
```

I would like to know of the best solution in pure Ruby, but am also open to suggestions from GSL etc.

**Performance**:

```
array_size = 4000
iterations = 1000

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report do
    iterations.times do
      a.each_with_index.map { |a, i| a if b[i] }.compact
    end
  end
end

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report do
    iterations.times do
      zipped = a.zip(b).select{ |z| z[1] }.map{ |n| n.first }
    end
  end
end
```

The performance below shows that not only is `map` on `each_with_index` more readable, but is also faster on large arrays.

```
     user     system      total        real
   0.610000   0.000000   0.610000 (  0.608642)
       user     system      total        real
   0.880000   0.000000   0.880000 (  0.882018)
```

Comment: The word `best` implies some sort of criteria to evaluate the algorithm. What do you mean with best? The most efficient? The most readable? The shortest?

Comment: A combination of performance and readability

Comment: I'd recommend using [Fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity) to write your benchmark. Fruity helps negate a lot of outside influences that can skew results. It shows your expressions run within 30% of each other, which isn't enough to worry about until you are into huge datasets. I agree with @muistooshort, that a database would be the right way to go if you're dealing with truly big amounts of data.

Comment: I think you are misusing the word "binary" here. Or, at least, you are using it in a confusing/misleading way.

Comment: I am aware that it is best to do this in a database or data library, however I am maintaining legacy code at the moment that has largely been replaced.

Comment: Where do `a` and `b` come from? Maybe the problem can be solved earlier on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turn the booleans into an Enumerator - no zip and no array lookup.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [true, true, false, false].to_enum

a.select{b.next}  # => [1, 2]
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but it either modifies `b` or requires an additional variable to hold the enumerator. Instead of turning `b` into an enumerator, you could also just call `a.select { b.shift }`.

Comment: @Stefan your solution will alter the elements of b to be an empty array?

Comment: @JohnLinux yes, you could `dup` the array and work with the copy instead.

Answer (score 6):

I find this quite readable and expressing the semantics clearly.

```
a.select.with_index {|_, i| b[i] }
```

As it turns out, [@steenslag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34212387/2988) beat me by 4 minutes with an even more elegant approach :-D

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for something shorter

`a.each_with_index.map { |a, i| a if b[i] }.compact` will do, but it is neither faster nor more readable. You'll have to define what best means.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is simply succinctness, and you already have a, b, and a results array defined, my first instinct would be to just say:

```
b.each_with_index { |val,i| results.push( a[i] ) if val }
```

Now, is this better? Not necessarily, no... but you'll want to expound upon your definition before anyone can conclusively say so.

Answer (score 1):

```
ans = []
b.each_with_index do |boolean, idx|
  ans << a[idx] if boolean
end
ans
```